# Question 6 Section Finite Fields Hungerford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Consider the following problem:

> If |K| = q and (n ,q) = 1 and F is a splitting field of $x^n-1_K$ over K, then prove that k = [F : K]
> is the least positive integer k such that $n | (q^k - 1)$.

Attempt : $|F| = q^k$ . Let p be a root of $x^n -1$=0 . But I am unable to think of any other details on how the question should be approached and I need help.

So, Can you please outline a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The roots to $x^n=1$ form a multiplicative group. Under what hypothesis does this group fit within $F^*$?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer, I am still not getting it.

Comment: Since$(n,q)=1$, $x^n-1$has no multiple root, so the multiplicative group it forms has $n$ elements. According to Lagrange’s theorem, $n|q^k-1$. On the other hand, for $l<k$, consider field $E$ formed by $x^p^l-x=0$, it’s easy to prove that $x^n-1$ splits in $E$.

Comment: ...if $n|p^l-1$ holds.